# Unable to access js and style sheet using Play

Tags: scala, playframework

Here I import from view file:

```
    <script src='javascripts/tic-tac-toe/main.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=stylesheets/tic-tac-toe/style.css'>
```

public folder structure:

[[image]]

routes file:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

When I try to access the view page I receive following error in firefox console and the files are not loaded :

> The resource from
>   “http://localhost:9000/assets/stylesheets/tic-tac-toe/style.css'” was
>   blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch
>   (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

How to access js and css resources from view file ?

I can browse directly locally to the files on the browser via the address bar:

- http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/tic-tac-toe/main.js
- http://localhost:9000/assets/stylesheets/tic-tac-toe/style.css

Comment: Use versioned() just like the line above?

Comment: @VM4 Apologies, I asked the wrong question. I have edited.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I need to prepend with "assets":

```
<script src='/assets/javascripts/tic-tac-toe/main.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/assets/stylesheets/tic-tac-toe/style.css'>
```